# Database structure when implementing a Slack style workspace/instance architecture

Tags: database, architecture

I'm working on an app that has a Slack style workspace architecture where the user can access the same function of the application under multiple "instances" (workspaces).

I'm going to continue with using Slack as an example to explain my issue.

When any action is taken in my application I need to validate that the user has the rights to perform an action on the specified resource and that the resource is within the same workspace as the user.

The first tables I create such as Users have a simple database relationship to the workspace. Using a WorkspaceId field in the Users table for example.

My issue is as I create more tables which are "further" away such as UserSettings which might be a one to one relationship to the Users table I now have to do a join to the Users record to get the workspace which the UserSettings record belongs to.

So now I am thinking is it worth adding a workspaceId value on all tables since I will endup doing a lot of JOINs in my database to continue verifying that the user has permissions to that resource.

Looking for advice/architecture patterns which may help with the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your main concern with multiple JOIN statements is that the query performance will suffer. Multiple JOIN statements don't always mean a query will be slow. The query performance depends on many factors, how large the dataset is and how well indexed it is, what database engine and ultimately what the query plan is. You'll only end up with lots of JOIN statements if you decide to normalize the database that way. Using a full third normal form is rarely the right choice for a schema because of the potential performance impacts it can have. Some duplication of data is generally okay, the trade off you are making is storage cost vs query performance. To decide on how to normalize the database there are many questions you should be asking here's some that come to mind:

1. What type of queries do you expect to make?
2. How often will each type of query be made?
3. How often will the data change and can a cache be used?
4. Does a different storage technology better suit the use case?
5. Is some of the data small enough that it can be all in one table?

In my experience designing user management systems, usually ends up with a cache or similar mechanism for having fast user to a given users permissions that has an acceptable expiry window. This means you are only querying the database for a given user at the expiry window and using the cache a majority of the time. This is why many security systems and user systems don't immediately update settings. The more granular and flexible the type of permission you want to grant user the more expensive the query is going to be because of the complexity. At which point you can decide to denormalize the data or use a coaching mechanism.